# Viewbinding in Fragment causes KotlinNullPointerException running within lifecycle scoped coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewbinding

I am setting up my Fragment like [suggested in Google docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) as such:

```
    private var _binding: MyBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = MyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

```
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
```

Now I'm calling a coroutine that to my understanding should be scoped to the lifecycle of this fragment. It has a longer network call, then a success:

```
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            when (myViewModel.loadFromNetwork(url)) {
                true -> responseSuccess()
                false -> responseFailure()
            }
        }
```

```
    private suspend fun responseSuccess() {
        binding.stateSuccess.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        // ...
    }
```

Now when I press the Android system-back button while `loadFromNetwork` is still loading the fragment gets destroyed and `onDestroyView()` is called. As such `binding` now is `null`. I'm getting a `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException`. What I not quite getting is why `responseSuccess()` is still being executed even though I thought that `lifecycleScope` is specifically meant for these kind of situations. According to [Google Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope):

> A LifecycleScope is defined for each Lifecycle object. Any coroutine launched in this scope is canceled when the Lifecycle is destroyed.

I understand this code can be fixed by a few changes and some manual null-checks, but I would like to understand how to fix this without boilerplate and in the intended manner. What is the purpose of using lifecycleScope to be lifecycle aware if not exactly this?

Comment: what sort of a suspend function is myViewModel.loadFromNetwork() ?? is it a cancellable suspend function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines cancellation is [cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative). It means it's a responsibility of a coroutine itself to check for cancellation. Most (or may be all) suspend operations in the coroutines library check for cancellation, but if you don't call any of them, you need to make your code cancellable as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable).

A better option to work with views in coroutines is to use [lifecycle extensions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#suspend) which suspend / cancel the coroutine automatically when the lifecycle state is not in a required state.

Also please note, that cancellation is just a regular `CancellationException`, so check you don't accidentally catch it.

Answer (score 1):

well it may not be a very clean way of handling it but I suggest to cancel the job in `onDestroyView` by your own self

define a job in class level like

```
lateinit var job:Job
```

then assign it like

```
job = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            when (myViewModel.loadFromNetwork(url)) {
                true -> responseSuccess()
                false -> responseFailure()
            }
```

and cancel it in onDestroView method before assigning null to _binding.

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        job.cancel()
        _binding = null
    }
```

the reason you get NULL POINTER EXCEPTION is that fragments have two lifecycles. 1)lifecycle and view lifecycle. _binding is assigned to null in onDestroyView but fragment lifecycle is still alive so coroutine's job is doing its work, when the network response arrives it run the launch block and wants to access binding object which is null by that time.

Comment: Not the exact same issue, but your comment helped me to solve mine. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

You are using lifecycleScope which is different to lifecycle of the fragment's view. So you have to use different scope `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {}`. Btw, the link to Google Docs exactly says so :)

Comment: I had the same suspicion when I was reading through the docs again. I think they are both pointing to the same thing, but just to make sure I have verified that the crash happens using `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {}` as well.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is there any fix?

Comment: Have you tried removing the _binding = null form the onDestroyView?

Comment: This would solve the issue but it would create a memory leak?